# Styling of label on a line in Tilemill

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

I currently have a line that I want to but a label onto in Tilemill. It currently looks like this:

[image: img]

But what I would prefer is something like this:

[image: img]

where the line isn't rendered around (and especially underneath) the label. Is there any way to archive that in Tilemill?

Answer (score 0):

One quick way of doing this is using 
`text-halo-fill` property in the label and a relatively large `text-halo-radius`

Also make sure the text-halo-fill color is the same as your background so it matches up.

Here's an example (I just edited one of my existing projects, so the colors are ugly, but it works)(right-click on image, select view image, to see the full image at greater detail).
[image]

Comment: Hm... is there no other way? Cause the color underneath my lines isn't always the same...